The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation. Fire store error
I am getting this error:

The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.

my firestore rules are :
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // This rule allows anyone with your Firestore database reference to view, edit,
    // and delete all data in your Firestore database. It is useful for getting
    // started, but it is configured to expire after 30 days because it
    // leaves your app open to attackers. At that time, all client
    // requests to your Firestore database will be denied.
    //
    // Make sure to write security rules for your app before that time, or else
    // all client requests to your Firestore database will be denied until you Update
    // your rules
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2024, 6, 1);
    }
  }
}



Please edit your question and show us the code that produces that error.

Did you enable App Check enforcement on the database by any chance?
